# What happens to the rest of the stack during a signal handler?

Tags: unix, pthreads, signals, tcpsocket

I've set up a signal handler in my main thread. A separate thread then sends my main thread this signal. My signal handler is being called appropriately, but I'm not sure what the 'State' of the main thread is at this point, and whether it can be recovered. basically, my main thread was blocked on a read() call, and a different thread has sent it a signal due to an extraordinary event. I thus want the read() call to fail (EINTR?), hence my other thread sending the main thread this signal.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you installed the signal handler.  If the signal handler was installed using `sigaction()` and without specifying the `SA_RESTART` flag, then the `read()` will fail with `EINTR` if it has not transferred any data yet.

In general, the thread that has handled a signal can continue normally after the signal handler returns.  That's really the whole point.

Remember though, that the signal might have arrived just *after* the `read()` had successfully returned, too - or worse, just *before* you called `read()` (in which case the `read()` will still block).